# What causes Azure to say CoreDNS has become unavailable?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, coredns

Started in the middle of the night last night. All services and databases seem healthy up to this point.

```
At Monday, August 21, 2023 at 3:43:33 AM MDT, the Azure monitoring system received the following information regarding your Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS):
We've temporarily lost connection to Core DNS. If the AKS cluster is running as expected, the status of the resource will change to Available after a few minutes.
Recommended Steps
Check back here for status updates. AKS is trying to recover this issue 
For coreDNS Troubleshooting please check the CoreDNS Troubleshooting  documentation.
Problems with CoreDNS may be a symptom of wider issues with you cluster, visit Diagnose and solve problems to further diagnose and troubleshoot the issue.
If this error persists and you are having issues interacting with your cluster contact support
```

Attempted to relaunch kubernetes pods, which resulted in a complete lockout of our system.

Answer (score 0):

> AKS is trying to recover this issue
> For coreDNS Troubleshooting.

Avoid Immediate Changes Be cautious with making any adjustments to your AKS configuration or deployments, as they might impact the stability of the cluster.

Create diagnostic settings as like below for metrics and logs.

[image]

- It's mentioned that an attempt to relaunch Kubernetes pods was made, which resulted in a complete lockout of the system.
- Simulate network disruptions by blocking DNS traffic between pods and the Core DNS service within the cluster.